# How to achieve Async file download with TPL in C#

Tags: c#, api, task-parallel-library, webclient

I have a windows console client that sleeps for few minutes and on waking up it requests new updates from Rest API. The request generates a response with json data involves a list of objects, each object consists of ID, description, screenshot being sent from the API to the client as URL. the console application is required to consume the json response, and for each object, it looks up the URL and try to download the corresponding image associated with each object in the list. The code is expressed as follows

```
foreach (var jobject in response)
{
    Console.WriteLine(jobject.id);
    Console.WriteLine(jobject.description);
    if (jobject.shotUrl != null)
    {
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
        webclient.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(jobject.shotUrl), "F:\\" + jobject.id + ".jpg");
    }
}
```

Sometimes there can be around 500 json objects which means 500 photo download ... again means creating 500 webclients. I feel this is not good idea.

My question is: can I gain performance if I rely on TPL? how to do so ?

Comment: Your question is contradicting itself. Do you want more *performance* or do you want less *resource usage*?

Comment: Keep in mind there is a default connection limit per endpoint, in a console app it is 2 IIRC. This means you will never not be able to download more than those 2 concurrently. see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rene in this question there is an answer shows how to increase concurrent connections http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206412/asynchronous-downloading-files-in-c-sharp

Comment: Also, I believe that if you use `System.Net.HttpClient` instead of `System.Net.WebClient`/`System.Net.HttpWebRequest`, the concurrent connections limit and similar API does not apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using HttpClient is much easier for concurrency, you can declare one private HttpClient for the class:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpClient _client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
```

And then you can write a method that downloads the files and saves them to disk like so:

```
 private async Task DownloadFile(string shortUrl, string destination)
 {
     using (var response = await _client.GetStreamAsync(shortUrl))
     using (var fileStream = File.Create(destination))
     {
         await response.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
         await fileStream.FlushAsync();
     }
 }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
try
{
     await DownloadFile(jobject.shortUrl, "F:\\" + jobject.id + ".jpg");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     // Do appropriate exception handling
}
```

And if you want to download all the files in parallel, You can use Task.WhenAll()

```
try
{
     var tasks = response.Select(j => DownloadFile(j.shortUrl, "F:\\" + j.id + ".jpg"));
     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     // Do appropriate exception handling
}
```

Comment: I benchmarked your code, its performance now is worse that my original work

Comment: Well to be honest, I didn't run the code at all, because I didn't have enough context (e.g. what's `response`). But I am sure with a bit of tweaking async code (especially the Task.WhenAll one) will provide better performance.

Comment: Downloading files in parallel should be done in `async` manner too: `async j => await DownloadFile`, not just the `j => DownloadFile`, because in second case it's done in concurrent manner and synchronously.

Comment: @VMAtm I think the `await Task.WhenAll()` takes care of that.